# How to get Clients service pack information using C# and asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

How to get Clients service pack information using C# and asp.net? I am able to get OS and framework information using c# code.

```
Response.Write("OS: " + Request.Browser.Capabilities["OS"] + "</br>");
Response.Write("Browser: " + Request.Browser.Browser + " " + Request.Browser.Version + "</br>");
Response.Write("Major Version: " + Request.Browser.MajorVersion + "</br>");
Response.Write("Platform: " + Request.Browser.Platform + "</br>");
Response.Write("Framework Version: " + Request.Browser.ClrVersion + "</br>");
```

I know about `servicePack = os.ServicePack.ToString();` which is giving me the service pack of the server not the client machine.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Unfortunately, you are limited by what information the browser is allowing javascript to obtain about the local PC.  As far as I am aware, this information does not include the .NET frameworks.

Comment: If you think about it, I think you would be glad that modern browsers and javascript don't just send every bit of information a web developer may want.  Imagine the ads and viruses and security vulnerabilities 0_o

Comment: This is what I received..Request.UserAgent
"Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; InfoPath.3)"

Comment: Ah, perhaps you are getting the .NET version then.  I wasn't aware IE8 did that.  I'm not sure you'll have as much luck with other browsers and versions though.  In any case, you should edit your question and add that information in another code box.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible. All you can do - is to get user agent like this:

```
var userAgent = Request.Headers.UserAgent.ToString();
```

However, if you want to have service pack information on your server you can go ahead with your own ActiveX component.

Answer (score 0):

A browser determines exactly what information it is willing to give out about the particular system it is installed on.  This typically does not involve intimate information about the .NET framework versions installed on the system.

If you can find a browser that is willing to transmit that information then you will have it, however I don't think any popular browsers will have it.  Depending on your needs, you could write a simple browser in something like VB6 that won't require any frameworks that could determine the installed frameworks and report it to any requesting web sites in the user agent string, however I have a feeling this may be beyond your project scope.